# How to make Multi builds in phonegap?

Tags: xml, cordova, ant, build, apk

Ladies and gents

I was going to ask "How to build 1001 apk(s) and apk in phonegap?" Smile

STEP1 If say I create

~\my-app/www
~\my-app/www1
~\my-app/www2
~\my-app/wwwN+1

each has one-to-be build as android apk

STEP2 borrow from this cool link 
http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-set-up-multiple-projects-to-share-the-same-ant-targets.html
... say 'tomcat-demo' 'tomcat-demo-2 ..N+1

He copied
build.properties 
build.xml 
file to a new project called 
'ant-utilities' and I renamed them to be 
build-main.properties and 
build-main.xml

He made a couple of very minor tweaks in each file, such as the 'project-name' property.

I wonder if it is doable for Phonegap?

Remember:
to build one single app we do:

1. SET ANDROID_HOME=C:\android-sdk
2. cd ~\my-app\platforms\android\cordova
3. build

That's it, APK is in folder 
~\my-app\platforms\android\ant-build
(CordovaApp-debug.apk)

Cheers
ps
In my only answer the list I followed to install and build

Comment: I get what you've done. I'm not sure what you're asking. Is there a specific technical question/problem you have?

Comment: `Who-here can volunteer and finish the job for Phonegap?` StackOverflow is not proper place to look for workers.

Comment: Thanks Steve and Dawson

Comment: oops, I installed phonegap and building Ok but doing as expected one build at time. I am not java coder, rather I am architect, what I need to do to adapt the example of tomcat etc into phonegap, so I reach for you ... of course any one participating is volunteering. |Philosophy:- My idea is to architect three 3clicks to translate hosts of texts into 90 languages, then convert with second click all into web format in compliance with phonegap both of which are done. Now I am wondering about one click build it all. Thanks again.

Comment: I downloaded Akptools and tested it. It is great